# Java 8 Streams: how can i stream another stream.How can i convert the code into java8 streams

Tags: java-8

Can someone please help me convert the below statements to Java8:

I have a hashmap like this:

```
private Map<String, Pair<List<XYZFiles>, List<XYZFiles>>> someMap;
```

I want to convert the below logic in java8:

```
private String searchFiles(String transmittedFileId) {

for (Pair<List<XYZFiles>, List<XYZFiles>> pair : someMap.values()) {
    List<XYZFiles> createdFilesList = pair.getKey();
    Optional<XYZFiles> xYZFiles= createdFilesList.stream()
                .filter(file -> 
                         file.getId().endsWith(transmittedFileId)).findFirst();
    if (xYZFiles.isPresent()) {
        return xYZFiles.get().getOriginId();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which package is your `Pair` class from?

Comment: its from javafx.util.Pair;

Comment: sorry typo its xyzFiles in the above case. It is a POJO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return someMap.values().stream()
           .map(Pair::getKey)
           .flatMap(List::stream)
           .filter(file -> 
               file.getId().endsWith(transmittedFileId)
           ).findFirst().map(XYZFiles::getOriginId).orElse(null);
```

I think that should do it. It basically does it flat map, which flattens all those lists into one big stream and `filter`s the whole thing.